# ES File Explorer - Remote manager read only

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer, ftp

I have just installed ES File Explorer on my Samsung, and started the Remote manager

I opened a FTP client on my PC and could connect to my tablet.. But I can't write files only read? Is this a bug or do I have to pay to get write access?

Comment: AFAIK all features like these for Android are read-only (I use a different file manager with a similar feature that is also read-only).

Comment: can you come across this with root?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, I have the same setup on my devices using both MiXplorer and ES explorer. The ftp server runs fine with read/write access (even on non-rooted device).

Perhaps your OS doesn't allow anonymous logins to have write access, in which case you need to configure a password authentication on your ftp server:

- Under remote manager, go to settings → Set manage account → Current user
- Input you new username and password
- Run the ftp server and enter the configured password on the target PC to access the files, and see if you have write access.

If you still having issues to access the files, then I recommend you'd use an alternative ftp client e.g [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) for Windows or [Fillezilla](http://packages.ubuntu.com/filezilla) for linux